# How to specify multiple nth days in Quartz?

Tags: c#, .net, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net-2.0

I have a requirement to execute a task every 3 months on the 3rd Tuesday and 3rd Thursday of the month.

The CRON expression that I have come up with is:

```
0 15 0 ? 3/3 3#3,5#3 *
```

However when I try to parse this using `Quartz 2.2.1`:

```
var cron = new Quartz.CronExpression("0 15 0 ? 3/3 3#3,5#3 *");
cron.GetNextValidTimeAfter(DateTimeOffset.Now).Dump();
```

I get:

> FormatException: Support for specifying multiple "nth" days is not
>   implemented.

Any ideas on how to get this implemented without having to resort to two separate CRON jobs, e.g:

```
// Tuesday
0 15 0 ? 3/3 3#3 *

// Thursday
0 15 0 ? 3/3 5#3 *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, this feature is not supported and as you have mentioned the best way to achieve what you want is by specifying two separate CRON jobs.